# Find the value of this 3 by 3 determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

[image: Here's what I did]

I've tried to solve it with minors, but it doesn't look right. Could you solve it using determinant's properties?

Comment: It's $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$.  See the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) for an explanation.

Comment: @Bye_World We haven't learn these signs yet.

Comment: Then you should probably just do it with minors.

Comment: @Bye_World Couldn't that be simplified in basic terms knowing the properties of determinants (or maybe some of them)

Comment: I'm not saying there aren't ways of avoiding minors in this case, but *I* don't see any of those hypothetical ways.  Expanding the determinant along the left column isn't very difficult in this case, though:  $$\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix} 1 & a & a^2 \\ 1 & b & b^2 \\ 1 & c & c^2\end{vmatrix} &= \begin{vmatrix} b & b^2 \\ c & c^2\end{vmatrix} - \begin{vmatrix} a & a^2 \\ c & c^2\end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} a & a^2 \\ b & b^2\end{vmatrix} \\ &= (bc^2-b^2c)+(ca^2-c^2a)+(ab^2-a^2b) \\ &= (a-b)(b-c)(c-a)\end{align}$$

Comment: @Bye_World How did you pass from second to third row? Is there any rule about that?

Comment: It just takes some algebra.  It's easier to go the other direction, though.  Just multiply out $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$ and you'll get back the second row.